# Keep getting errors when opening terminal window

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

Every time I open a Terminal window (I use `HyperTerm`/`Hyper.app` but it does the same thing on Mac's default terminal), I get this error:

```
': not a valid identifier
: command not found
': not a valid identifier
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
: command not found
```

I think it has to do with my bash profile, but I don't understand because I can't see any errors in it.

This is my `.bash_profile`:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 2.7
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

#Path Java
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.7`
#or
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`

#yagarto
export PATH=$HOME/yagarto/yagarto-4.7.2/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/yagarto/yagarto-4.7.2/tools:$PATH

#GO
export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
export GOPATH=$HOME/Desktop/Dev/Go

#Ruby Gem
export GEM_HOME=$HOME/.gem
export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME

# Ruby PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bin:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: If you `source` your profile (or whatever the equivalent is on OSX) with print statements before each command, you should be able to drill down to which one if giving you a problem?

Comment: i tried your profile in iTerm2 and didn't get any errors

Comment: I also recommend you to add "set -x" at the beginning of your profile to see which lines produce errors.

Comment: I tried sourcing and apparently, it doesn't come from bash_profile. What could it be then? It has to be a script that's run whenever i open terminal tho, I don't have bash_rc so it can't be that...